# How can I inspect 3D model exactness?

Tags: unity, 3d, graphics, models, assets

I am neither a game designer nor a graphic designer. I am a .Net and C# 
software developer. I have a game project and I've still been studying to learn 
game concepts and technolgies for a year.

I've decided to create a 3D based and networked MMO game with Unity3D.
I've planned to hire graphic artists to do my game assets. 
However, I only know what I want? In other words, I only know concept of 3D models.

What I have to request from graphic artists and how can inspect their work?
Do I have to determine some quality criterias or something like this?
Same questions are also valid for humanoid and NPC animations.

Thanks

Comment: "exactness" is a vague word in this context, what qualities of 3D models are you looking for? realism? detail? How much are they optimized for  game rendering? Well, art can't be exact. What qualities are you looking for ?

Comment: Of course I should describe some quality standards and criterias in order to able to inspect them. But I don't know how to describe them. What are they should be?

Comment: How they look is very subjective. But regarding optimizing them for a game this question might help http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/33016/how-does-3d-games-work-so-fluent-provided-that-each-meshs-size-is-so-big

Comment: very old post but it might help you out - http://www.rsart.co.uk/2007/08/27/yes-but-how-many-polygons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many points you can check:

- does it load (import) correctly in your Unity
- how many polygons
- how many textures
- how many bones
- how many draw calls does it incur in the engine. in forward mode / and deferred mode.
- is it manifold
- does it create seams while lightmapped
- previous point is linked to secondary UV set unwrapping quality.
- does it have a normal map / specular map / roughness map
- a wrinkle map...
- hit boxes... etc.

A specialized game asset artists will be very good on all these points.

If your question is about how can I interview artists to determine how good they are at each of these points, maybe you should require for a demo asset, from one of your descriptions (concept) that the person could provide as an application entry.

When you make a concept, usually people do a concept art. Which is a bunch of drawings/paintings that takes a day or two to compose, to a profesionnal. If you are a programmer, it will be what one calls "programmer's art" but if you have any expressivity at all it should be enough to convey your intent.
The concept art represents facial view / side views, some material description, accessories list, details emphasis (like "I need scars here").